# Test controller in Jasmine AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am trying to test my controller and service using Jasmine.

I have a home controller defined like below

```
angular.module('TFPMPortal').controller('HomeController', Home);

    Home.$inject = ["$cookieStore", "PartsTrackHttpCallService", "$scope"];

    /* @ngInject */
    function Home(cookieStore, PartsTrackHttpCallService, scope) {
}
```

Here is my unit test using Jasmine

```
describe('HomeController', function () {
    var scope, ctrl, cookieStore, PartsTrackHttpService;

    beforeEach(module('TFPMPortal'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        ctrl = $controller('HomeController', {
            cookieStore: null,
            partsTrackHttpService: PartsTrackHttpService,
            $scope: scope
        });
    }));

    it('should call the init data function', function () {
        var count = 0;
        PartsTrackHttpService.httpCall("common/tfpminitdata", scope.mc.PartsTrackProfile, true, true).then(function (response) {
            count = response.data.SiteList.length;
        });
        expect(scope.greeting).toBe("Greetings Frederik");
    });
});
```

I am getting error - 'HomeController' is not a function, got undefined.

Answer (score 0):

In each test suite (test file) you need to make sure you load the Angular module that contains the code you wish to test.

In this case, the your `HomeController` was declared on the module named "TFPMPortal". Load this module in your test:

```
beforeEach(module('TFPMPortal'));
```

Note that this loads the "TFPMPortal" module, but if your controller/tests are using services/factories/etc from other modules in your app, you need to load those modules too. For example, it looks like you'll need to include 'ngCookies' (b/c you use `$cookieStore`):

```
beforeEach(module('TFPMPortal', 'ngCookies'));
```

**EDIT**: Actually on further review, your test code above is fulfilling the `$cookieStore` dependency by passing `null`, so referencing the `ngCookies` module may not required ... on the other hand, there's no need to do this b/c Angular can inject the real `$cookieStore`.

Comment: lol this is the third time you changed your comment. Let me know when you make a final version :P

Comment: I loaded the module 'TFPMPortal' like you suggested but still some long binary error is coming in gitbash.

Comment: In that error message should be another statement indicating what is wrong. Angular likes to generate URL's for errors, I'm guessing that's what you're seeing. Most likely you just need to load another module that your controller is using. The answer is in the error message.